# Automating Homebrew

Tags: macos, shell, bash-scripting, homebrew

I'm currently using the Homebrew package manager, and I have to say that it is really really great!

My question is: there is a way to automate `brew update` and `brew upgrade` in order to execute this commands when a shell is opened?
I'm not very expert about bash programming, so I'm not sure if this thing is possible or not, I'm currently using iTerm.

Comment: See [This SO question and excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528282/how-to-update-homebrew-with-cron-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @fd0 that this probably shouldn't be automated to the point of launching it for every shell. This can get ugly if you have multiple shell windows. I opted for a semi-automated solution by creating an alias in my `~/.profile` that performs several brew functions. Check out [this post](https://superuser.com/a/975878/175099) for details.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Automating such a process in a shell startup file is a bad idea. Every new instance of a shell would execute both commands. You could place a function in your `.bashrc` and and call the function which would cut down on the number of characters that you need to type but that's not a real game changer.

Comment: Is possibile to write the function in order to execute it only the first time the shell is opened?

Comment: If you want to automate the process then use `launchd` or `cron`. Don't use a shell startup file.