# How can I remove outdated installed versions of Homebrew packages?

Tags: macos, package-management, homebrew

How can I remove outdated versions of [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) packages that are installed side-by-side with current versions?

Comment: Since version [2.0.0, cleanup happens automatically, unless you opt-out](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/).

Answer (score 355, accepted):

The [cleanup](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-uninstall-old-versions-of-a-formula) (`brew cleanup`) command will remove outdated installed package versions. To affect a particular package/formula, you may supply a formula name like so: `brew cleanup $FORMULA`. To simulate cleanup, i.e. see what would be removed, you may use the `-n` option: `brew cleanup -n`.

Comment: For the record: `brew cleanup` only cleans outdated package versions if you have the newest version installed, so first `brew upgrade` then `brew cleanup`

Comment: Holy crap. That just gave me more than 3G back. Who knew…

Comment: `This operation has freed approximately 17.2GB of disk space.`

Answer (score 91):

@aknuds1 is right about `brew cleanup` so I'll just add that I have an alias in my `~/.profile` that does all my brew-related cleanup, including cask update/cleanup

```
alias brewski='brew update && brew upgrade && brew cleanup; brew doctor'
```

I end with `brew doctor` to make sure all packages are correctly symlinked, e.g., `awscli` seems to have a problem with this on the regular so I constantly have to unlink/relink. Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT:** As it was pointed out to me in the comments, `brew cask` functionality has been merged into the homebrew core. These commands were also throwing errors, so references to `brew cask` have been deleted.

**EDIT2:** As I run this daily, I noticed the following comment today. I've updated the command accordingly

```
    Warning: We decided to not change the behaviour of `brew upgrade` so
    `brew upgrade --all` is equivalent to `brew upgrade` without any other
    arguments (so the `--all` is a no-op and can be removed).
```

Comment: You don't need to do `brew upgrade brew-cask` anymore as since [this pull request](https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/pull/15381) `brew update` will also now upgrade homebrew-cask automatically.

Comment: @Lantrix Thanks for that update. I've edited my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: `brew upgrade --cleanup` will remove old packages as new packages are installed.

Comment: I dont advise to use `brew upgrade` but instead to use `brew outdated` and then upgrade each one of the packages by `brew upgrade PACKAGE` that way you have more control

Comment: As `brew upgrade` is a single command to upgrade all packages, it works well for automation. Optionally, you can `pin` package versions you want to keep and upgrade the rest all at once.

Comment: `brew upgrade` runs `brew update` before looking for package updates. Thus, `brew update` is unnecessary.

Comment: Would it make sense to run `cleanup` before `upgrade`? Would that keep the least-outdated version remains? I'm guessing this could be useful for emergencies or something, while still ensuring that no old stuff accumulates?

Comment: `Unless HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP is set, brew cleanup will then be run for
the upgraded formulae or, every 30 days, for all formulae.
// Error: invalid option: --cleanup`

Answer (score 39):

Just for the records, you can clean the outdated versions of the packages that you are about to upgrade using the --cleanup flag:

`brew upgrade --cleanup <package_name>`